# How can I perform the same query on multiple tables in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, workbench

I'm working in SQL Workbench in Redshift. We have daily event tables for customer accounts, the same format each day just with updated info. There are currently 300+ tables. For a simple example, I would like to extract the top 10 rows from each table and place them in 1 table.

Table name format is Events_001, Events_002, etc. Typical values are Customer_ID and Balance.

Redshift does not appear to support declare variables, so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: You should not do that. Do not generate tables all the time. A table structure should be fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've effectively invented a kind of pseudo-partitioning; where you manually partition the data by day.

To manually recombine the tables create a view to union everything together...

```
CREATE VIEW
  events_combined
AS
  SELECT 1 AS partition_id, * FROM events_001
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS partition_id, * FROM events_002
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS partition_id, * FROM events_003
  etc, etc
```

That's a hassle, you need to recreate the view every time you add a new table.

That's why most modern databases have partitioning schemes built in to them, so all the boiler-plate is taken care of for you.

But RedShift doesn't do that.  So, why not?

In general because RedShift has many alternative mechanisms for dividing and conquering data.  It's columnar, so you can avoid reading columns you don't use.  It's horizontally partitioned across multiple nodes (sharded), to share the load with large volumes of data.  It's sorted and compressed in pages to avoid loading rows you don't want or need.  It has dirty pages for newly arriving data, which can then be cleaned up with a `VACUUM`.

So, I would agree with others that it's not ***normal*** practice.  Yet, Amazon themselves do have a help page (briefly) describing your use case.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-time-series-tables.html

So, I'd disagree with "never do this".  Still, it is a strong indication that you've accidentally walked in to an anti-pattern and should seriously re-consider your design.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, super-helpful. I've only been with the company a few weeks and must admit it's the first time I've encountered such a structure for tables. Worth suggesting a revised approach as my 1st port of call.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out many small tables in Redshift is really inefficient, like terrible if taken to the extreme.  But that is not your question.

You want to know how to perform the same query on multiple tables from SQL Workbench.  I'm assuming you are referring to SQLWorkbench/J.  If so you can define variables in the bench and use these variable in queries.  Then you just need to update the variable and rerun the query.  Now SQLWorkbench/J doesn't offer any looping or scripting capabilities.  If you want to loop you will need to wrap the bench in a script (like a BAT file or a bash script).

My preference is to write a jinja template with the SQL in it along with any looping and variable substitution.  Then apply a json with the table names and presto you have all the SQL for all the tables in one file.  I just need to run this - usually with the psql cli but at times I'm import it into my bench.

My advice is to treat Redshift as a query execution engine and use an external environment (Lambda, EC2, etc) for the orchestration of what queries to run and when.  Many other databases (try to) provide a full operating environment inside the database functionality.  Applying this pattern to Redshift often leads to problems.  Use Redshift for what it is great at and perform the other actions elsewhere.  In the end you will find that the large AWS ecosystem provides extended capabilities as compared to other databases, it's just that these aren't all done inside of Redshift.